# How do I search the collection of a collection in my LINQ Where clause?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I've got the following ADO.NET Entity Framework Entity Data Model:

[image: ADO.NET Entity Data Model]

I want to find all the Policyholders with both a Service of a given Id and also a Keyword of a given Status.

This LINQ Does Not Work:

```
Dim ServicesId As Integer = ...
Dim KeywordStatus As Integer = ...

Dim FoundPolicyholders = From p As Policyholder In db.PolicyholderSet.Include("Keywords").Include("Services") _
                         Where p.Services.Id = ServicesId _
                         And p.Keywords.Status = KeywordStatus _
                         Select p
```

The Where clause cannot search the p.Services and p.Keywords EntityCollections in that way.

> 'Id' is not a member of
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection(Of
>   ....Service)'.

What is the correct LINQ syntax to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
db.PolicyholderSet.Where(ph =>
   ph.Services.Any(s => s.Id == someId) &&
   ph.Keywords.Any(kw => kw.Status == someStatus))
```

Why does your query not work? Because `p.Services` and `p.Keywords` are a `Service` and a `Keyword` collection - they have not property `Id` or `Status` hence you cannot use `p.Services.Id` or `p.Keywords.Status`.

Visual Basic…

```
Dim FoundPolicyholders = From p As Policyholder In db.PolicyholderSet.Include("Keywords").Include("Services") _
                         Where p.Services.Any(Function(s) s.Id = ServicesId) _
                         And p.Keywords.Any(Function(k) k.Status = KeywordStatus) _
                         Select p
```

Comment: The function "Any" was the clue I needed.  Thank you.